# AJAX is returning readystate=1

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, ajax, flask, xmlhttprequest

I am using Flask with Python. From the Flask method I am trying to return HTML table rows in an AJAX call.

The HTML page has:

```html
<div>
<table id="tableQuestions">

</table>
```

```
//AJAX Requests to get
function loadQuestions() {

  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   alert(xmlHttp.readyState + " " + xmlHttp.status);
   if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
       var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
       console.log(response);
       document.querySelector("#tableQuestions").innerHTML=response;
   }
   xmlHttp.open("GET", '/gS', true);
   xmlHttp.send(null);
  }
}
```

The Flask route has:

```
#test.mix() returns html table rows

@gbp.route('/gS')
def gS():
    test=mn()
    response = make_response(test.mix(quesCount=4),200)
    response.mimetype="text/html"
```

In the Safari debugger I can see that the `responseText` has the table data from the server, but `readystate` remains 1 and `status` = 0.

[image]

Could you please suggest how I can overcome this issue?

Comment: What issue are you facing? If `readyState` is `1` then, then it wont enter your if-statement. It will become `4` after the request/response in a alter stage.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", '/gS', true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

inside your `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange` callback function, which leads to strange effects.

The following code (untested) should behave better:

```
//AJAX Requests to get
function loadQuestions() {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("GET", '/gS', true);

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert(xmlHttp.readyState + " " + xmlHttp.status);
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
      var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
      console.log(response);
      document.querySelector("#tableQuestions").innerHTML=response;
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! that was so silly, i didnt notice i had placed curly brackets  incorrectly